# par with foreach results random order but not with map

Tags: scala

I was just going through `par` method and found out that with `foreach` it results sequence in **random** order but its not the same case with the `map`.

I know par uses some algorithm to achive parallel computation but then why its not then happening with the map

```
scala> val petnames = Seq("tiger", "coco", "mini", "dora","dodo", "momo", "cod", "neo", "simbha", "dante")
scala> petnames.par.foreach( x => println(x.capitalize))
Neo
Cod
Coco
Mini
Dante
Momo
Dora
Tiger
Dodo
Simbha
scala> println(petnames.par.map(_.capitalize))
ParVector(Tiger, Coco, Mini, Dora, Dodo, Momo, Cod, Neo, Simbha, Dante)
```

Comment: The `map` was executed in parallel _(you can add a print inside to check)_ and thus in random order. But the results are aggregated to preserve the order.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez map dose not produces random order, its the foreach does

Comment: If you put a `println` in the map, it will still print in random order. But `map` preserves order of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually we differentiate between *temporal* and *spatial* order. Parallel collections execute operations out-of-order in the temporal sense, however in the spatial sense they are in-order. Ssemantics [state](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html#Semantics)

> Side-effecting operations can lead to non-determinism

`foreach` takes a side-effecting operation `println`, hence the effect is likely to execute "out-of-order". Note how side-effects have no "structure" to them, they are just something that happens. On the other hand, `List[T]` has structure and `map`ping over a list is a *structure-persevering* operation. Thus

> The “out of order” semantics of parallel collections only means that
>   the operation will be executed out of order (in a temporal sense. That
>   is, non-sequentially), it does not mean that the result will be
>   re-“combined” out of order (in a spatial sense). On the contrary,
>   results will generally always be reassembled in order– that is, a
>   parallel collection broken into partitions A, B, C, in that order,
>   will be reassembled once again in the order A, B, C. Not some other
>   arbitrary order like B, C, A.